# OpenGL with OpenMP always segfault

Tags: multithreading, opengl, loops, for-loop, openmp

I have in my program a loop that will fill an 3D cube with pixels (GL_POINTS), so to speed up things a little I thought i could use OpenMP and separate this for loop in my multi-core processor.

The problem is that any time I use OpenMP in the loop the program segfaults, here is the code of the loop:

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int a = 0; a < m_width * m_height; a++)
{
    uint8_t r, g, b;
    r = m_data[a * m_channels];
    g = m_data[a * m_channels + 1];
    b = m_data[a * m_channels + 2];

    glColor3ub(r, g, b);
    glVertex3f(r / 255.0 - 0.5, g / 255.0 - 0.5, b / 255.0 - 0.5);
}
glEnd();
```

As you can see, the code just get some information from m_data array and then call glColor3ub and glVertex3f with it, if I run this code without the #pragma the code runs great.

The gdb shows me that the program segfaults when it reach the glColor3ub, making clear that the problem is something with openGL, maybe the function is not thread-safe? Can I make something to correct the code?

Comment: What led you to believe that this would work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't mess with a single OpenGL context and multithreading, or guard every use of OpenGL by a critical section (which won't buy you anything performance-wise). What you can probably do is use vertex arrays/buffers (which will be faster anyway) and fill their data using multiple threads before drawing it in a single thread.

What should happen if one thread sets the current color and gets unscheduled before it draws the vertex? But what definitely will happen is that the driver gets interrupted in the middle of some operation and its internal data gets totally messed up.

OpenGL is definitely not thread safe.

Comment: You must always only issue OpenGL calls in your app's main thread.

Comment: OpenGL is thread safe in the way, that a context may be active in only one thread at a time. And it should be noted that while multiple contexts with shared lists can be active in their own threads at the same time, if the share the target framebuffer this is a recipe for bad performance and all kind of issues.

Comment: Christian, can you give me some example or some place to me study vertex arrays? I'm really new to openGL so I don't hame much idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Just to make myself clear, what I want to optimize in this code is the access to the m_data array in the loop, this array is a frame from a video, where I read all pixels and show it in an rgb cube, so what I wanted to get with this code is to cut the for loop in half (i have a 2 core processor) when reading the data.
If I got right, with an vertex array I can read the data in multithread, and then draw it, right?

Comment: @Eduardo essentially yes. But your code looks like you won't even need to copy the data into a vertex array. Just use `m_data` as vertex array directly (with the vertices' type being `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, of course) and use a vertex transformation that does the [0,255] to [0,1] maping. This way you prevent the copy completely.

Comment: @Christian Rau Ok, I changed the code and now the code is working great with the vertex array, I used the m_data array to the glColorPointer, but for the glVertexPointer I created a new array with just 3 channels instead of 4, and then make the transformation from [0, 255] to [0, 1], so far so good, the code is running great now with OpenMP and is really fast. Thanks a lot for the help!
I just read your message and you talked about a vertex transformation, I will try it now!

Comment: @Eduardo Oh sorry, it seems you cannot use `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for `glVertexPointer`, so forget this idea (it would work with shaders and custom attributes, though).

Comment: @Christian Rau Oh, I see, well, it's ok, the code is now flying compared to the old one thaks to you :), but let me ask you one more thing, you talked about an way to do a normalization from [0,255] to [0,1] using vertex transformation right? I tried find something on the internet but no luck, can you explain what are you talking about? even if I still need to copy the data to another array I still need to do the normalization(/ 255.0), so if I can eliminate this step the code will be even faster! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Eduardo Just use standard vertex transformations (I hope you are acquainted with transformations and the OpenGL transformation matrices). `glScaled(1.0/255.0, 1.0/255.0, 1.0/255.0)` on the modelview matrix will devide all coordinates by 255, for example. And this might indeed be faster, as you spare alot of CPU floating point divisions for the cost of nothing (the vertices need to be transformed anyway, no matter by what values).

Comment: @Christian Rau Perfect! glScaled worked like a charm, Thanks a lot!
Actually I'm really new to OpenGL, but loving it, I'm still learning the basics from it so I doesn't know about glScaled for example, but so far so good, thanks again!