# GLFW3 with OpenMP segfaults on glCallList (amongst other places in glfw)

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, openmp, glfw

I've got a problem with some code that is supposed to use both glfw3 and OpenMP (using g++ 5.3.0 on OSX, by the way).  This is a simplification of some math software that I've been working on writing, and it seemed like it was going well up until this point.  The code itself it **huge**, and even my example is pretty freaking big (I hijacked one of my old tutorial projects that already had glfw working), so I'll attach the git repo that the code lives in for duplication.  I've looked at other glfw3 problems arising from multithreading, and come up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933812/threading-this-method-produces-a-segfault-why) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233477/opengl-with-openmp-always-segfault).

[glfwAppTutorial git repo!](https://github.com/cedelmaier/glfwAppTutorial)

The problem exists in the gears application.  When I compile it without OpenMP, it works.  When I compile it with OpenMP and only use 1 thread, it works.  When I move to using 2 threads, it segfaults on the glfwPlatformPollEvents call.  I checked the thread id via the std::this_thread::get_id() call for when I create the context, and then when I am going to update it, but it still seems to segfault when I move to multiple omp threads, but only after I add a **specific** set of commands.  It get's weirder than that.  The seminal piece of code is where I start doing some computationally heavy stuff, which of course I want to parallelize.  The code looks like this (glfwAppTutorial/gears/src/gears.cpp::glloop for main version, extraneous stuff removed for clarity):

```
// gears.cpp excerpt
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int tid;
    double *fx, *fy, *fz;
    tid = omp_get_thread_num();

    fx = frc_ + (3*tid)*10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3*10; ++i) {
        fx[i] = 0.0; // BOOM!!!!!!!!!, including this segfaults, but not here...
    }
    fy = frc_ + (3*tid+1)*10;
    fz = frc_ + (3*tid+2)*10;

    std::cout << "Running on thread: " << tid << std::endl;

    #pragma omp for schedule(runtime) nowait
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // simulate work
        std::mt19937_64 eng{std::random_device{}()};  // or seed however you want
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist{10, 100};
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{dist(eng)});
    }
    // synchronize if we need to
    #pragma omp barrier

} // pragma omp parallel
```

Where frc_ is defined earlier (and zeroed to be all 0.0 doubles as):

```
// gears.hpp excerpt
nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
frc_ = new double[3*10*nthreads];
for (int i = 0; i < 3*10*nthreads; ++i) {
    frc_[i] = 0.0;
}
```

Of course, in this example, everything is running under (glfwApp.cpp):

```
//glfwApp.cpp excerpt
void glfwApp::glfwloop() {
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(_window)) {
        this->glloop();

        glfwSwapBuffers(_window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

The line that causes the segfault is where fx[i] = 0.0, but that line isn't the actual segfault source.  The program segfault at either gleCallList, or in glfwPlatformPoll.  So does anybody know what might be going on?  A computation-only version that doesn't use glfw3 is fine, and I've used valgrind (or on OSX, Instruments) to check for possible problems.  All I'm doing is some pointer arithmetic that should be fairly straightforward, but for some reason isn't.  I'll try to work on creating a **much** simpler example, since I realize this is probably going to be impossible to follow, but it's been driving me nuts for a few days now.

**Here is the stack trace from OSX** because Xcode and gdb are being stupid right now

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000110

VM Regions Near 0x110:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000106019000-0000000106020000 [   28K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/*

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00007fff8d03f57c gpusLoadCurrentVertexArray + 132
1   com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver    0x000000010b66c695 gldUpdateDispatch + 2819
2   GLEngine                        0x00007fff8b69bad4 gleDoDrawDispatchCore + 533
3   GLEngine                        0x00007fff8b63e636 gleSetupAndDrawArraysOrElementsOutOfLine_ListExec + 886
4   GLEngine                        0x00007fff8b5c8a6a gleCallList + 170
5   gears                           0x000000010601bc25 gears::draw() + 199
6   gears                           0x000000010601c285 gears::glloop() + 33
7   gears                           0x000000010601dd2a glfwApp::glfwloop() + 60
8   gears                           0x000000010601dcea glfwApp::start() + 24
9   gears                           0x000000010601d04a main + 171
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff967475ad start + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the constructor of `gears` is called from within the dynamic scope of a parallel region, `omp_get_num_threads()` returns 1, therefore `frc_` is not spacious enough to hold data for more than one thread and the heap gets corrupted by the code shown in the first segment. Try replacing `omp_get_num_threads()` [here](https://github.com/cedelmaier/glfwAppTutorial/blob/94c2c9537edd08100277a2fa082e37fd69ad140b/gears/src/gears.hpp#L22) with `omp_get_max_threads()` and see if it helps. Also, make sure that `omp_set_dynamic(0);` is present somewhere in your code and that no `omp_set_num_threads()` is called in between, otherwise the team size might vary from one parallel region to another and with that the value of `omp_get_num_threads()`.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm so stupid.  I haven't gotten nailed by this one in years.  Hopefully this is also the problem with the main code.

Comment: Overwriting things on the heap can result in seemingly random failures at many other places of the code.